# Countdown Timer Based on Day?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a countdown timer that counts from Monday to Wednesday, Wednesday to Friday and Friday to Monday. Everything seems to be working ok except for the actual day value. That is not calculating correctly.

Before I had it set up to just countdown to Monday and that was working fine for me. This is the code I was following - https://vincoding.com/weekly-repeating-countdown-timer-javascript/

```js
var curday;
var secTime;
var ticker;

function getSeconds() {
  var nowDate = new Date();
  var destinationDay;
  var weekDay = nowDate.getDay();
  if (nowDate.getHours() >= 24) {
    weekDay++;
  }
  // in case it is Saturday after 8PM we would have a 7 as week day which should be changed to 0 (sunday).
  weekDay = weekDay % 7;

  if (weekDay > 1 && weekDay <= 3) {
    destinationDay = 3;
  } else if (weekDay > 3 && weekDay <= 5) {
    destinationDay = 5;
  } else {
    destinationDay = 1;
  }

  var counterTime = new Date();
  // calculate the date by adding an offset based on current and target date.
  counterTime.setDate(counterTime.getDate() + (destinationDay + 7 - weekDay) % 7);
  counterTime.setHours(24);
  counterTime.setMinutes(0);
  counterTime.setSeconds(0);

  var currentTime = nowDate.getTime(); //current time
  var destinationTime = counterTime.getTime(); //countdown time
  var diff = parseInt((destinationTime - currentTime) / 1000);
  startTimer(diff);
}

function startTimer(secs) {
 secTime = parseInt(secs);
 ticker = setInterval("tick()",1000);
 tick(); //initial count display
}

function tick() {
 var secs = secTime;
 if (secs>0) {
  secTime--;
 }
 else {
  clearInterval(ticker);
  getSeconds(); //start over
 }

 var days = Math.floor(secs/86400);
 secs %= 86400;
 var hours= Math.floor(secs/3600);
 secs %= 3600;
 var mins = Math.floor(secs/60);
 secs %= 60;

 //update the time display
 document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = days;
 document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = ((hours < 10 ) ? "0" : "" ) + hours;
 document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = ( (mins < 10) ? "0" : "" ) + mins;
 document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = ( (secs < 10) ? "0" : "" ) + secs;
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
  getSeconds();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countholder">
 <div><span class="days" id="days"></span><div class="smalltext">Days</div></div>
 <div><span class="hours" id="hours"></span><div class="smalltext">Hours</div></div>
 <div><span class="minutes" id="minutes"></span><div class="smalltext">Minutes</div></div>
 <div><span class="seconds" id="seconds"></span><div class="smalltext">Seconds</div></div>
</div>
```

It should countdown to each day and move on to the new day after midnight.

Comment: Can you explain what does if (weekDay > 1 && weekDay <= 3) mean? FYI 0 is for Sunday, 1 is for Monday, and so on.